# Kendo grid: How to create perform some taks on Add new row and not on Edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, datagrid, kendo-grid

**In my KendoGrid I want to add default value for input field in my popup form.**

I have created a function that I intend to call on clicking Create button, but the following function does not work. I searched a lot but could not find any help, so it would nice if someone can give me a hint where the problem is.

```
 function add_m(e) {
    debugger;
    $("#DeviceIP").val("123");
}
$("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({
     //   debugger;

     dataSource: dataSource,
     scrollable: false,
     //toolbar: ["create"],
     toolbar: [
                  {name: "create",text: "add new turbine"}
              ],
     columns: [
                  { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
                  { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', id:'Producer'},//editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor,
                  { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '220px',id:'Model' },
                  { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px', editor: deviceTypesList },
                  { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '220px' },
                  { field: 'Username', title: 'Username', width: '120px' },
                  { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },
                  { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px' },
                  { field: 'TurbineId', title: 'TurbineId', width: '120px', hidden: true },
                  { field: 'device_id', title: 'device_id', width: '120px', hidden: true },
                  { field: 'ModelProducer', title: 'Producer/Model', hidden: true, editor: modelProducer },
                  {command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;"}
             ],
        //{
        //    command: [
        //                 {
        //                     name: "Edit",
        //                     click: function (e) {
        //                             temp = $(e.target).closest("tr"); //get the row
        //                     }
        //                 }
        //             ]
        //}


     editable: "popup",
     create:add_m,
```

Comment: Check edit function, I have tested with my code, it is working for create only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to assign val or attribute dynamically use

[edit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit):

```
edit: function(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew()) {
       e.container.find("input[name=test]").val(5555); // name changed, but worked for me
      // e.container.find("input[name=device_id]").val(123);
    }
}
```

or

[beforeEdit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-beforeEdit):

```
beforeEdit: function(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew()) {
      $("#DeviceIP").val("123");
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but the problem is,create and edit buttons both open the same editor,and I need to write a function for create without affecting the edit one

Comment: have you added this line? `if (!e.model.isNew()) {` . I have updated answer

Comment: @I get "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'enable' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: that was just an example, you need to change to as per your need. I think adding `$("#DeviceIP").val("123");` in beforeEdit function will work for you

Comment: I just noticed there was `!` condition for isNew(), I have edited

Comment: in my edit I added  function (e) {
                                        debugger;
                                        if (e.model.isNew()) {
                                            e.preventDefault();

                                            $("#DeviceIP").val("123");
                                        }

Comment: when I wana create,it comes in to the if clause,but does not change the val!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153350/discussion-between-jigar-shah-and-mrslt).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `beforeEdit` event, not `create`. It fires when the `create` button is clicked in the toolbar.

Comment: the problem is for create and edit,i have the same form!how can I write a function only for the create without affedting the other one

Comment: you can use `isNew()` to check whether it is create or edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/e8xqogs2/).

Below is the code snippet that pastes the default value for `DeviceIP` on `Add row event`.

```
$("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({
....
.........
//ON CLICK ADD/EDIT BUTTON FOR PRODUCT ITEM
        edit: function(e) {

            // CHANGE ADD/EDIT PRODUCTITEM POPUP FORM TITLE
            if (e.model.isNew()) //ON ADD NEW
            {
                $(".k-window-title").text("Add New Turbine");
                // HERE e.container IS THE ADD/EDIT POPUP FORM ELEMENT
                e.container
                    .find("[name=DeviceIP]") // get the span element for the field
                    .val("123") // set the value
                .change(); // trigger change in order to notify the model binding

            } 
            else // ON EDIT
            {
                $(".k-window-title").text("Edit Turbine");
            }
        }
........
....
});
```

Here is the complete code from the DEMO fiddle.

```
(function () {



      var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: {
                id: 1,
                DeviceIP: "192.168.1.1",
                Producer: 'Producer',
                Model: 'Model',
                DeviceType: 'DeviceType',
                Description: 'Description',
                Username: 'Username',
                Password: 'Password',
                PublicIP: '216.168.123.156',
                TurbineId: 1,
                device_id: 2,
                ModelProducer: 'ModelProducer',
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: 'id',
                    fields: {
                        DeviceIP: {},
                        Producer: {},
                        Model: {},
                        DeviceType: {},
                        Description: {},
                        Username: {},
                        Password: {},
                        PublicIP: {},
                        TurbineId: {},
                        device_id: {},
                        ModelProducer: {},

                    }
                }
            }
        });


    $('#grid').kendoGrid({
     dataSource: dataSource,
     scrollable: false,
     //toolbar: ["create"],
     toolbar: [
                  {name: "create",text: "add new turbine"}
              ],
     columns: [
                  { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
                  { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', id:'Producer'},//editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor,
                  { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '220px',id:'Model' },
                  { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px' },
                  { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '220px' },
                  { field: 'Username', title: 'Username', width: '120px' },
                  { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },
                  { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px' },
                  { field: 'TurbineId', title: 'TurbineId', width: '120px', hidden: true },
                  { field: 'device_id', title: 'device_id', width: '120px', hidden: true },
                  { field: 'ModelProducer', title: 'Producer/Model', hidden: true },
                  {command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;"}
             ],
        editable: 'popup',
        //ON CLICK ADD/EDIT BUTTON FOR PRODUCT ITEM
        edit: function(e) {

            // CHANGE ADD/EDIT PRODUCTITEM POPUP FORM TITLE
            if (e.model.isNew()) //ON ADD NEW
            {
                $(".k-window-title").text("Add New Turbine");
                // HERE e.container IS THE ADD/EDIT POPUP FORM ELEMENT
                e.container
                    .find("[name=DeviceIP]") // get the span element for the field
                    .val("123") // set the value
                .change(); // trigger change in order to notify the model binding

            } 
            else // ON EDIT
            {
                $(".k-window-title").text("Edit Turbine");
            }
        }
    });
})()
```